# Lightweight Linux web server that supports CGI

Tags: linux, web-server

Is there any webserver that supports CGI (not FastCGI/Rack/WSGI) and that is easy to setup? (lightweight and portable if possible, just need to copy the binary to another similar machine)

So I'll just need to put some CGI scripts there, and then when I visit that script using a browser, the script gets exectured and displayed in the browser.

OS: Linux

Comment: Take a look at XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org. It has a portable version too.

Comment: sorry, I just edit my question, I prefer lightweight too, XAMPP just too big for me

Comment: It is not portable, but it is lightweight: nginx http://www.tautvidas.com/blog/2012/01/nginx-with-php-fcgi-a-lightweight-web-server/

Comment: umm.. thats FastCGI not CGI.. thanks anyway..

Comment: Yes, Nginx counts as one of its (security) features that it cannot run CGI. Feature or not, few people care, since FastCGI typically far preferred over CGI.

Comment: yes, for now I only need CGI >___< hopefully it's capable for handling 1k request..

Comment: What Linux distribution do you have? If you don't know, try `cat /etc/issue` and `uname -a`.

Comment: Arch Linux, 3.14.2 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Acme Labs' [thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/) - easy to set up, fast and supports CGI.

Most recently I put it one some Raspberry Pis.

It's a single binary, when you launch it you give it the name of a config file.

Answer (score 3):

[busybox](https://busybox.net/) can be built with http and cgi modules.

Let me quote the project's [description](https://busybox.net/about.html):

> BusyBox combines tiny versions of many common UNIX utilities into a
>   single small executable. It provides replacements for most of the
>   utilities you usually find in GNU fileutils, shellutils, etc. The
>   utilities in BusyBox generally have fewer options than their
>   full-featured GNU cousins; however, the options that are included
>   provide the expected functionality and behave very much like their GNU
>   counterparts. BusyBox provides a fairly complete environment for any
>   small or embedded system.
>
> BusyBox has been written with size-optimization and limited resources
>   in mind. It is also extremely modular so you can easily include or
>   exclude commands (or features) at compile time. This makes it easy to
>   customize your embedded systems. To create a working system, just add
>   some device nodes in /dev, a few configuration files in /etc, and a
>   Linux kernel.

Comment: Added a description.

Answer (score 2):

[uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html) with CGI (only requires Python)

Install using:

```
curl http://uwsgi.it/install | bash -s cgi /tmp/uwsgi
```

create a setup configuration so you can run it without too many arguments, for example `test.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
http = :8081
http-modifier1 = 9
#uid = 
#gid =
check-static = ./www
static-skip-ext = .php
static-skip-ext = .rb
static-skip-ext = .py 
static-skip-ext = .lua
static-index = index.html
async = 16
ugreen = true
socket = 127.0.0.1:9000
cgi = ./cgi
cgi-allowed-ext = .php
cgi-allowed-ext = .rb
cgi-allowed-ext = .py
cgi-allowed-ext = .lua
cgi-index = index.rb
```

create a testing script, for example `./cgi/test.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby    
require 'cgi'    
cgi = CGI.new
puts cgi.header
puts '<html><body>ENV: <ol>'
ENV.each do |k,v|
  puts "<li><b>#{k}</b> #{v}</li>"
end
puts '</ol>POST: <ol>'
cgi.params.each do |k,v|
  puts "<li><b>#{k}</b> #{v}</li>"
end
puts '</ol></body></html>'
```

start the server using:

```
./uwsgi test.ini
```

test it using browser or curl:

```
curl -d 'test2=2' localhost:8081/test.rb?test=1
```

Comment: `curl http://..  | bash` allows anyone in your local network to install arbitrary software on your machine.

Comment: Sending the response of an un-encrypted protocol to command interpreter is dangerous as @phihag explains. Use `https` where possible, or better yet, download the script, examine it first, before executing with the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `ncat --exec`. See https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-exec.html

Here is an example:

```
ncat --keep-open -p 5555 -l --exec /bin/bash
```

You can then make multiple interactive connections to a shell (or any other linux program that interacts through stdin/stdout) using telnet or nc:

```
$ nc localhost 5555
echo hi
hi
```

Comment: You do realize the question contains the qualifier "... that supports CGI" do you? Do you have a reference where `nc` gains CGI support in some version? I don't think it has because `nc` is supposed to be used as a bare-bone user interface to sockets.

Comment: I see now that this answer shows a way to interact with a shell remotely via a tcp socket (rather than say ssh), which can be useful but is not what the OP asked for.